# How do I change the default password configuration in Subversion (svnserve)?

Tags: svn

I'm creating a bunch of new repos, and each will be accessed by the same users.  By default, SVN will create a passwd file with entries like this:

```
[users]
# harry = harryssecret
# sally = sallyssecret
```

I want to new repos to be created with my list of users, but I haven't been able to find a way do that.  Does anyone know how?

Thanks.

Evan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `[general]` section of the `svnserve.conf` there is a path to the password file.  This file should govern the access to the repos that svnserve is currently serving, therefore there should only be one file.  The [svnbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch06s03.html) has more details on svnserve and how to configure it.

Comment: Yes, but as far as I can tell, there is a svnserve.conf for each repository.  I essentially need access to the template from which svn creates a new repository, so when i create a new repo it is created with the modified version of the file.  Does that help, or am I missing something?

Comment: you should only have one instance of svnserve running so you only need one config, not one for each repo. You can then access any repo on your machine by passing the absolute path to it.  For example `svn://host.example.com/usr/local/repositories/project1`

Comment: OK, not sure if it matters, but I running on Windows Server 2008.  I realize that there is only one svnserve instance, but I'm not aware of a global svnserve.conf - there is one for each repo.

Comment: There should be a global config in the `%APPDATA%\Subversion` folder.  You can have a system wide one that lives in the inside the common Application Data location.  The link http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07.html#svn-ch-7-sect-1 tells you a little more about this.

Answer (score 3):

Slightly old but it's surprisingly hard to find an answer to this question online. I just gave up and looked through the SVN source code and figured it out. Hope this is useful to others.

The "template" for the default config files in {repodir}/conf is actually hard-coded into the svn binaries. There's no actual template file that's being copied over when you create a new repo.

I think the easiest solution for people who create lots of new repos is to just make your own template config files and write a script to clobber the generated ones.